# How to use usort to sort MongoDB query result

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, loops, sorting

Trying to sort array present in object but getting error **usort() expects parameter 1 to be array** I have not found any useful solution for this error on anywhere, How can I sort my array[detail] by total array elements count.

Here is my code -

```
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$cursor = $manager->executeQuery("DB.col", $query);
foreach($cursor as $row) {
  foreach($row->detail as $item) {
    function cmp($a, $b) {
      return $a['detail'] > $b['detail'];
    }
    usort($row, "cmp");
  }
}
```

Schema of my array:

```
array(
    [0]=>stdclass object( 
        [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId Object (
                    [oid] => 5f55f95815a8508e2deac8dd
                )
        [Date] => 9/12/2020
        [title] => ram
        [roll.n] => 5
        [detail] => Array(
            [0] => stdclass object( 
                [title] => John
                [id] =>55
                [class] => six)
            [1] => stdclass object( 
                [title] => Doe
                [id] =>550
                [class] => six)
            [2] => stdclass object( 
                [title] => Jean
                [id] =>9
                [class] => one)
            [3] => stdclass object( 
                [title] => AI
                [id] =>90
                [class] => one)
            )
    )

    [1]=>stdclass object( 
        [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId Object (
                [oid] => 5f
        )
        [title] => sunny
        [roll.n] => 50
        [detail] => Array(
            [0] => stdclass object ( 
                [title] => lilly
                [id] =>551
                [class] => six)
            [1] => stdclass object( 
                [title] => Doel
                [id] =>550
                [class] => six)
            [2] => stdclass object( 
                [title] => rehaman
                [id] =>9
                [class] => one
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Why is your code for sorting `$row` inside a foreach that _uses_ `$row`?

Comment: printing other values of array-> details with the help of it, you can check array structure above detail contains elements which i am printing,

Comment: What do you mean by "sort my array by total array elements count"?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans how can i sort whole object by detail array count

Comment: @Nick I am trying to sort in descending order by total elements present in detail like for first object 4 elements are in [detail] array I am trying to sort by its count

Comment: It looks like what you want might be to replace both `foreach` loops with `usort($cursor, function ($a, $b) { return count($a) - count($b); });` Swap `$a` and `$b` in the `count` calls if you want to sort descending.

Comment: The $row is the key-value object itself. It makes no sense to do usort on it. Also your comparison function is comparing 2 array ('detail') which doesn't make any sense, either. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Any solution for sort in descending order by [detail] count?

Comment: Ask your database to do that for you as part of your query, because that's one of the jobs it was designed for. And it can do it way more efficiently than your PHP code can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [executeQuery](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.executequery.php) method returns a [MongoDB\Driver\Cursor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-cursor.php). It implements the [Traversable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) interface so you are allowed to do `foreach` on it. This might have confused you to think it is an array. It's actually not.

To do usort on the result, you need to first turn the cursor into an array. Then, if I understand correctly, you are to sort the rows by the size of their 'detail' array like this:

```php
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$cursor = $manager->executeQuery("DB.col", $query);
$rows = $cursor->toArray();

usort($rows, function ($a, $b) {
  return sizeof($a->detail) <=> sizeof($b->detail);
});

return $rows;
```

Note: if the order is reversed, simply swap the `$a->detail` and `$b->detail` in the comparison function of `usort()` call.

If you're not using PHP 7, you might not have the [spaceship operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.spaceship-op) `<=>` to use with. Simply use this comparison function instead:

```php
usort($rows, function ($a, $b) {
  if (sizeof($a->detail) == sizeof($b->detail)) {
    return 0;
  }
  return (sizeof($a->detail) > sizeof($b->detail)) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

P.S. You should really upgrade to PHP 7. PHP 5.6 has been dropped from support for years. It's not as performant and less secure.

Comment: Which line? And what PHP version are you using?

Comment: I am using PHP version 5.6  getting error on this line -  return sizeof($a->detail) <=> sizeof($b->detail);

Comment: Seriously, you need to upgrade your PHP.

Comment: How can i order by date after using usort ?

Comment: I don't see any date or time field in your data example. How do you know what the date is for an object?

Comment: Field name is data i have just added it please check the code, I am trying to show data by current date i.e today

Comment: The basic principles are similar. You can write a different comparison function to compare the date field. Given your date format, you cannot do it with simple string comparison. Try to convert them to DateTime before compare. Check [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).